# Reagan's quote on the best social program

Tags: politics

According to

http://www.azquotes.com/quote/653562

Ronald Reagan said that "I believe the best social program is a job"

Now, I am not sure if I understand this correctly.

For, the term *social program* could mean two things for me:

- a government action to create a job, a program for the *society*
- a personal activity with other people

Or, is this a pun intended for having two possible meanings?

Comment: In the United States, "social program" is often used for all sorts of government activities that would, in other English-speaking countries, be lumped under "the Dole" - for example, vouchers for food payment, vouchers for housing payments, reduced-cost transportation for school children, and so on. What President Reagan was saying was that rather than providing these sort of supports, it is better that the person being supported instead be employed (implicitly, not in a make-work job created specifically to get them "off the Dole").

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin With references (I'm not saying they'll be easy to find, or this would be genref) this would be a good _answer_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - If I could have _found_ references, I'd have posted it as an answer. :(